# R :Fitting survival trees with time-varying covariates in RandomForestSRC

Tags: r, random-forest, survival-analysis

In the package LTRCtrees one can fit a decision tree to the special format of the Surv function :Surv(time, time2, event) as per below example

```
set.seed(0)
library(survival)
library(LTRCtrees)
## Create the start-stop-event triplet needed for coxph and LTRC trees
first <- with(pbcseq, c(TRUE, diff(id) !=0)) #first id for each subject
last <- c(first[-1], TRUE) #last id
time1 <- with(pbcseq, ifelse(first, 0, day))
time2 <- with(pbcseq, ifelse(last, futime, c(day[-1], 0)))
event <- with(pbcseq, ifelse(last, status, 0))
event <- 1*(event==2)

pbcseq$time1 <- time1
pbcseq$time2 <- time2
pbcseq$event <-  event

## Fit the Cox model and LTRC trees with time-varying covariates
fit.cox <- coxph(Surv(time1, time2, event) ~ age + sex + log(bili), pbcseq)
LTRCIT.fit <- LTRCIT(Surv(time1, time2, event) ~ age + sex + log(bili), pbcseq)
LTRCART.fit <- LTRCART(Surv(time1, time2, event) ~ age + sex + log(bili), pbcseq)
```

Is it possible to use the same function on a Random Forest using the RandomForestSRC library

```
library(randomForestSRC)
RF.fit <- rfsrc(Surv(time1, time2, event) ~ age + sex + log(bili), data=pbcseq, nsplit = 3, ntree = 100, importance = TRUE)
```

Which generates an error:

```
Error in parseFormula(formula, data, ytry) : 
  Survival formula incorrectly specified.
```

Comment: Can you show where time varying data has been properly handled with randomForestSRC? What kind of searching have you done? Agoogle search with `randomForestSRC "time varying"` brought up evidence that this was not possible so I'm downvoting for apparent lack of effort at research.

Comment: Actually after multiple trial I managed to make it work for rfsrc too in the format
v.obj <- rfsrc(Surv(stratum*2-1,stratum*2, case) ~ . , data = x2, 
               ntree = 100, block.size = 1)

But I had too many R Session Errors when using large dataset, so I moved ultimately to XGboost. Thanks for your attention. I am not sure how to close the topic though.

Comment: You could write up a short answer and give yourself the check as a suitable wait.

Answer (score 0):

[This paper](https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-019-0863-0#Sec19) by Wongvibulsin, Wu, and Zeger (2019) extends the randomForestSRC package to handle TVC, but you may need to contact the authors for any relevant code.